# How to change the position of a popup text?

Tags: css, popup

The CSS for the popup text (French) is:

```
   .label-mobile-languageselector .popuptext {
        visibility: hidden;
        width: 360px;
        background-color: #668A04 !important;
        color: #fff;
        text-align: left;
        /* border-radius: 6px; */
        padding: .5px 0;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
        bottom: -67%;
        left: -271%;
        margin-left: -80px;
    }
```

> My task is to shift the popup text little bit towards the bottom which
>   is little upwards as shown in the image.

I tried changing the position of a popup text by using the `text-align` property but unfortunately I am unable to move towards the bottom.

```
text-align: center;
text-align: left;
text-align: right;
```

[image]

The CSS for the image(as shown above) before the popup text is:

```
.label-mobile-languageselector .popuptext:before {

content:url('img/globe.png');
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
  width: 30px; /* whatever width you need */
  height: 29px; /* whatever height you need */
  margin-right: 0.5em; /* whatever margin is needed to separate the image from the text */

}
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9x1rpz2b/2) ( At this moment the popup not working not sure why )

Comment: try using margin-top  instead

Comment: @Saurav Rastogi You can use this link jsfiddle.net/9x1rpz2b/2 ( At this moment the popup not working not sure why )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excerpt from my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aod3gs0t/):

```
.label-mobile-languageselector .popuptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 360px;
    background-color: #668A04 !important;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 15px 0 0;
        /* Added padding, adjust to your needs */
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    /*height: 29px !important;*/
        /* height removed */
    /*bottom: -67%;*/
        /* bottom removed */
    left: -271%;
    top: 48px;
        /* top added */
    margin-left: -80px;
}

.label-mobile-languageselector .popuptext::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -16px;
        /* top changed to the arrow height */
    left: 58.2%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 8px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #668A04 transparent transparent transparent;
    transform: rotateX(180deg); 
}
```

Comment: You can use this link https://jsfiddle.net/9x1rpz2b/2/ ( At this moment the popup not working not sure why )

Comment: Can you try with the Fiddle that I posted in my answer? http://jsfiddle.net/aod3gs0t. You see that it works there.